# Crystal Report Problems with Redhat 6.4

Tags: tomcat, crystal-reports, rhel6

Crystal-reports is working fine on Redhat 5.4, but when I deployed it on Redhat 6.4 I am getting the following error:

com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Please help me with this.

Stacktrace is as follows.

```
com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError---- Error code:-2147467259 Error code name:failed
at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.request(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.x.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.q.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument.do(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument.if(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ClientDocument.open(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.sdk.ReportClientDocument.open(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jsp.report_002dviewer_jsp._jspService(report_002dviewer_jsp.java:137)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:94)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:324)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.cj.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.cj.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.jb.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bm.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bm.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bm.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.c3.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.c3.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.c3.goto(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.lq.d(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.lq$a.e(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.lq$a.c(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.lq.c(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.eq.d(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.eq.void(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.C(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.ae.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.ae.if(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.if(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.C(Unknown Source)
at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.c.a(Unknown Source)
at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.b.v.if(Unknown Source)
Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.cj.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.cj.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.jb.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bm.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bm.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bm.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.c3.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.c3.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.c3.goto(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.lq.d(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.lq$a.e(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.lq$a.c(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.lq.c(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.eq.d(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.eq.void(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.C(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.ae.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.ae.if(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.if(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.C(Unknown Source)
at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.c.a(Unknown Source)
at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.b.v.if(Unknown Source)
at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.request(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.x.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.q.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument.do(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument.if(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ClientDocument.open(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.sdk.ReportClientDocument.open(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jsp.report_002dviewer_jsp._jspService(report_002dviewer_jsp.java:137)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:94)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:324)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.cj.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.cj.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.jb.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bm.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bm.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bm.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.c3.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.c3.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.c3.goto(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.lq.d(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.lq$a.e(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.lq$a.c(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.lq.c(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.eq.d(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.eq.void(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.C(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.ae.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.ae.if(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.if(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.C(Unknown Source)
at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.c.a(Unknown Source)
at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.b.v.if(Unknown Source)
at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.request(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.x.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.q.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument.do(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument.if(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ClientDocument.open(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.sdk.ReportClientDocument.open(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jsp.report_002dviewer_jsp._jspService(report_002dviewer_jsp.java:137)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:94)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:324)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)
```

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace

Comment: oh sorry. Done ....

Comment: Did you check whether your version of crystal reports is supported by RH 6.4?